# share object between worker processes

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to run `f(x)` on many different worker processes which run one (bonus points for more than one) remote machine, where `x` is a large object.

My interactive R session runs on `node0` and I use the `parallel` library, so I do the following:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(rep("node1", times = 64))
clusterExport(cl, "x")
clusterExport(cl, "f")

clusterEvalQ(cl, f(x))
```

The problem is that sending `x` takes quite a while, because it is transferred to each worker process separately from the machine where the master process runs through the network connection.

Question:
is it possible to send `x` only once to each node and have the worker processes copy it locally?

Comment: Are you sure that the object is sent for each iteration?

Comment: the object is sent to each worker process one after another in the line `clusterExport(cl, "x")`, this is very slow, because it happens through a network connection. It would be enough to send it once and then copy it in memory from one worker process to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the connection between master and the remote host is what is the bottleneck, you can transfer one copy to the first worker and then cache it to file and have the other workers read the data from that cache file.  Something like:

```
library("parallel")

## Large data object
x <- 1:1e6
f <- function(x) mean(x)

## All N=64 workers are on the same host
cl <- makeCluster(rep("node1", times = 64))

## Send function
clusterExport(cl, "f")

## Send data to first worker (over slow connection)
clusterExport(cl[1], "x")

## Save to cache file (on remote machine)
cachefile <- clusterEvalQ(cl[1], {
  saveRDS(x, file = (f <- tempfile())); f
})[[1]]

## Load cache file into remaining workers
clusterExport(cl[-1], "cachefile")
clusterEvalQ(cl[-1], { x <- readRDS(file = cachefile); TRUE })

# Resolve function on all workers
y <- clusterEvalQ(cl, f(x))
```

Comment: certainly works, I was hoping for some piping/socket magic to avoid going through the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses `fifos`, I am not sure how portable this is, works under Linux, I am not sure how this compares performance wise with `@HenrikB`'s anwser:

```
library(parallel)

# create a very large cluster on a single (remote) node:
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)

# create a very large object
o <- 1:10

# create a fifo on the node and retrieve the name
fifo_name <- clusterEvalQ(cl[1], {
                        fifo_name <- tempfile()
                        system2("mkfifo", fifo_name)
                        fifo_name
})[[1]]

# send the very large object to one process on the node and the name of the fifo to all nodes
clusterExport(cl[1], "o")
clusterExport(cl, "fifo_name")

# does the actual sharing through the fifo
# note that a fifo has to be opened for reading 
# before writing on it
for(i in 2:length(cl)) {
  clusterEvalQ(cl[i], { ff <- fifo(fifo_name, "rb")  })
  clusterEvalQ(cl[1], { ff <- fifo(fifo_name, "wb")
                        saveRDS(o, ff)
                        close(ff)                    })
  clusterEvalQ(cl[i], { o <- readRDS(ff)
                        close(ff)                    })
}

# cleanup
clusterEvalQ(cl[1], {   unlink(fifo_name)            })

# check if everything is there
clusterEvalQ(cl, exists("o"))

# now you can do the actual work
...
```

Comment: this failed for a `data.table`, apparently this does not work for any object type.

Comment: please expand on your "this failed for a `data.table` ..." claim.  It's important to back this up/explain so that others won't draw the incorrect conclusions.  Could it be that you simply need a `library(data.table)` _on the worker_?  (this is explained in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html)